# Why is SQL Server not using Index for very similar datetime query?

Tags: sql, indexing, primary-key

i have a table on SQL Server with about 1 million rows.
It has an ID (PK), a status (int) and a datetime column.
Also I've created an Index on the datetime column.

Now I've found out an effect, which I don't understand.

```
SELECT status
FROM table
WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '2010-01-01T00:00:00' AND '2010-01-02T12:00:00'
```

This statement returns 3664 rows. It runs about 150ms and the execution plan shows that its doing an index seek with key lookup.

Now, if I change it as following (just change the hour from 12 to 13):

```
SELECT status
FROM table
WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '2010-01-01T00:00:00' AND '2010-01-02T13:00:00'
```

This statement returns 3667 rows. It runs about 600ms and the exuction plan shows that its using the primary key!

I just don't understand it. For 3667 and more rows its always using the primary key, even if the seek is much faster.

Is there an explanation?

Comment: Try to include the `status` column in your index on the datetime field - I almost guarantee that doing so, the query optimizer will use that index and be much faster than when doing a clustered index scan....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`status` is not included in the index on `datetime` so it needs to do key lookups for each matching row to retrieve this value.

As the range grows (and hence number of lookups required) it estimates that it will be quicker just to scan the whole (covering) clustered index avoiding the lookups. Possibly incorrectly in your case. The point at which it switches from one plan to the other is known as [the tipping point](http://sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx).

You should check if the estimated vs actual number of rows is out of whack (perhaps some rows that would have matched the range have been deleted since the statistics were last updated).

Or maybe the index scan is more expensive than the costing assumptions assume due to high levels of fragmentation or for some other reason the [costing assumptions](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/an-introduction-to-cost-estimation/) made do not reflect the actual relative performance in your environment.

Comment: @pst - Because the wider the time range the greater the estimated rows and hence the tipping point is reached. The query doing the CI scan includes an extra hour.

Comment: I've deleted all further indexes and statistics before I created the new index. There is indeed a "tipping point" (in this case '2010-01-02T13:00:00'). For every larger period its always using the primary key, which makes it obviously slower. Though, I don't get it, because the index seek should be still faster, since the primary key always has to comb through each row, right?

Comment: @Powerslave - It assumes that it is faster to do a (largely sequential IO) scan than lots of random IO lookups and costs the two options accordingly. It can switch from one to the other at quite a small proportion of the table. This is discussed more in the tipping point link in my answer. The costing assumptions assume that queries will be executed with a cold cache so all data needs to be brought in from disc.

Comment: I read your articles and got a little bit more enlightened. Now I know, the tipping point is indeed my problem here and covering indexes will not run in the tipping point. But I noticed some other problem. When I use parameters for the datetime conditions, the index on datetime (no covering) will NEVER be used, its always using the primary key (clustered index scan). But shouldn't we use always parameter and how can you explain this now?

Comment: @Powerslave - Are you using parameters or variables? The explanation will be different depending on which one you are using but for both adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query will get it to take account of the actual values passed. If you are using parameters then due to parameter sniffing the plan is compiled as per the first parameter value passed and reused for other invocations. If it is variables then it does not look at the value at all as the statement is compiled before the variables are assigned to.#

Comment: NHibernate creates the queries with variables. I realize thats getting more and more complicated the deeper i dig into and that there's no ultimate solution for writing performant queries. Thanks so far!